# Angular2 rc4 bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have just updated my angular2 app from RC1 to RC4. I've followed the guide exactly but for some strange reason the bootstrapping of the app in my main.ts file isn't working. My code is:

```
import  { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { enableProdMode }    from '@angular/core';

import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './service/routes.service';

import { AppComponent }   from './components/app.component';

enableProdMode();

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
]);
```

I'm getting the error message:

> [ts] Module
>   '"/Users/bradbeighton/Documents/Dev/coffeezan/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index"'
>   has no exported member 'bootstrap'. import bootstrap

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

The packages that I have installed are exactly the same as what Angular suggest. So I'm confused why the bootstrap module isn't being found?

I'm also having another issue with setting up the routing the way they suggest in the tutorial.

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home.component/home.component';';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '/home', component: HomeComponent },
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

I don't know whether I'm just being stupid here or whether I've installed the wrong packages? Help please??

EDIT:

My systemjs.config file is pretty standard but here it is:

```
var isPublic = typeof window != "undefined";

/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app':                        'client', // 'dist',
        '@angular':                   (isPublic)? '@angular' : 'node_modules/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': (isPublic)? 'angular2-in-memory-web-api' : 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs':                       (isPublic)? 'rxjs' : 'node_modules/rxjs',
        'ng-semantic':                (isPublic)? 'ng-semantic' : 'node_modules/ng-semantic'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng-semantic':                { main: 'ng-semantic', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade'
    ];
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });
    var config = {
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Comment: at safer side, delete your `node_modules` folder, update `package.json` and again do `npm install`...

Comment: @micronyks good idea but sadly I have already tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: can you please share your systemjs.config.js as well?

Comment: I think, according to error, it can't find that module.

Comment: @Sanket I've edited my question with the systemjs.config file.

Answer (score 0):

When referring **.umd.js** files, you need use **bundles**. Please refer below block-

```
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
```

See if this helps.